# how to get venv to point to older python version

Tags: python, django, pip, python-venv

I am trying to clone and run a project on my mac.

but on the installation options I have to run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get an error and I am pretty sure its because the project runs on python 2.7 while my venv runs on 3.4

```
(venv)/*
$ python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

however when I am outside of venv I run am back onto the correct python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

WHy is venv running 3.4? How can I change venv to not run 3.4 and just run the 2.7

Do I have to update an environment or venv variable on my system? I can't find where python is in my system. Also any advice on what commands to run would be appreciated as I am a bit new to python/django.

perhaps the pip I have in venv is wrong, idk. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you executing the `pip`  command inside the venv?

Comment: yes as per the projects installation instructions: # Install venv
virtualenv venv --distribute
# Launch venv
source venv/bin/activate
# Install deps
pip install -r requirements.txt
# Create database
python manage.py migrate
# Create admin
python manage.py createsuperuser
# Launch
python manage.py runserver

Comment: I would assume that the project would come with the relevant virtual environment it was created in. When does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the option `-p` to specify, which version should be used, when you create the virtual environment.

For example:

```
virtualenv -p python2.7 venv
```